# Docker mount error in windows

Tags: docker

I am getting below error when i try to run docker in windows not sure why its happening.

```
docker run -d -P -v //c/Users/uzh352/.docker/machine/certs://mnt/certs -e "DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=true" -e HOST_IP=192.168.99.100 -v //c/git/Conversation-Platform/microcore/microcore/src/test/resources/extra://extra hello/world
    1f2f3a63b48e854e7f9e4db970286754788a5d6ab491501e4fbe975521f5bc7d

docker logs containerid 

standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is related to "Shared Drives". You have to mark the project folder as shared, so docker has access to it.